# I want the text of quote id should displayed on console.But instead of quote id it is displaying review on console?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

1) I want to capture quote id.But instead, it will capture review on the console.

2) I am using selenium web driver with java.

3) Just want the quote id to printed on the console all the details are mentioned below.

I want to capture quote id from a webpage using selenium web driver.Below are my dom structure and the code that I have used. But instead, it is printing the review text is part of XPath.

Dom structure of my page:

```
  <tbody>
<tr>
<tr id="pricerow" valign="top">
<td nowrap="nowrap">
  3661017
<br/>
<a class="selectMenuHome" style="color: gray; text-transform: none; text-decoration: underline;cursor:hand;" alt="TestSITA" title="TestSITA">Review</a>
</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">UNITED KINGDOM</td>
<td>London</td>
<td>   1 Ropemaker Street, London, United Kingdom </td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">3456789</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap"/>
<td nowrap="nowrap">2 Mbps</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">ME</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">Business VPN Corporate</td>
<td nowrap="nowrap">211</td>
```

Xpath that have used: `(.//*[@id='pricerow']/td[1])[1]`

Quote capture code:

```
public static void QuoteCapture() throws Exception{
            logmessage = ExcelUtils.getCellData(Constant.testcaserownum,
                    Constant.TestStepID)
                    + "; "
                    + ExcelUtils.getCellData(Constant.testcaserownum,
                            Constant.TeststepDescription)
                    + "; Action: Capture and stored value";
            Log.info(logmessage);
            String[] fetchfrompage = null;
            ActionElement = FindElement();
            if (ExcelUtils.getCellData(Constant.testcaserownum, Constant.Data1)
                    .isEmpty()) {
                fetchfrompage = ActionElement.getText().split("\n");

                ValueCaptured.add(fetchfrompage[0]);
                // ValueCaptureindex=ValueCaptureindex+1;
                int size = ValueCaptured.size();
                size = size - 1;
                logmessage = ValueCaptured.get(size)
                        + "; Value has been stored in index: " + size;
        }
            Log.info(logmessage);
        }
```

Comment: Which _element_ / _text_ are you referring as `quote id`? I don't even see any text as `review` in the shared _HTML_.

Comment: I edited the HTML structure of my page.Please into it again quote id is 3661017 and when you scroll right you will see  tag as review

Comment: Where is the xpath called? I don't see it being used in the code you shared

Comment: The XPath is given in excel sheet.There are many calling functions in this code.I want to know if this line is correct:  fetchfrompage = ActionElement.getText().split("\n");

Comment: What does `ActionElement.getText()` give you? Does it give `3661017  Review` or just `Review`?

Comment: It is giving me review only